# Make substring using a specific delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make a substring of a column value using a specific delimiter.I tried SUBSTRING_INDEX,but it doesn't work for SQL.Is there any way to achieve this??

Column values are:

```
ARTCSOFT-1111
ARTCSOFT-1112
ARTCSOFT-1113
```

and I want to achieve the same thing in SQL:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code,'SOFT-',1))
```

i.e I want the number after SOFT- in my substring.I can't use only - because before SOFT- there is chance that - may occur(rare case,but I don't want to take a chance)

Comment: Is it fair to rephrase to "return text after the last '-' character in a string" or are there some without any "-" in there?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Nope, you got it right. I want the text after the last "-" and all column values have "-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using just `SUBSTRING` . For example

```
SELECT 
     SUBSTRING(code, CHARINDEX('SOFT-', code)  + 5, LEN(code)) AS [name]  from dbo.yourtable
```

hope this helps.

**Tested Result:**

[image]

Comment: The above query gives me SOFT-1111,SOFT-1112... as result. But I want just the numbers i.e 1111,1112,...

Comment: but with same column values and same query i have checked and got correct result.

Comment: may be you have missed something from query,pls check.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RIGHT(Code , CHARINDEX ('-' ,REVERSE(Code))-1)
```

Read this as: Get the rightmost string after the first '-' in a reversed string - which is the same as the string after the last '-' character.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query:

```
  select substring(col,charindex('-',col)+1,len(col)-charindex('-',col)) from #Your_table
```

**Explanation of Query**:
Here Charindex find the '-' delimeter [length] IN Given String and now that Result[length+1] is our starting point and ending length is [len(col)-starting length] gives ending point and then use substring Function to split a string according to our requirement.

**Result of Query:**

```
Required_col
1111
1112
1113
```